# jQuery fileupload url with query params

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

The endpoint I'm uploading a file to requires a query parameter: `?name=foo.txt`. However, when using the [fileupload plugin](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload) for jQuery, it strips any parameters out of the url when I set it like this:

```
$('#file-input').fileupload({url: '/upload?name=foo.txt'});
```

When I check the value of `url` it returns `/upload`. I can't find anywhere in the documentation that allows you to set query parameters. Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I believe it only allows you to send via `POST` or `PUT`.

Comment: Hmm. Maybe the guy doing this before did it wrong then... Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out that it actually is possible to do this. I had problems elsewhere in my code.